# d3js v5 : Can't figure out how to use Observable notebooks

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, d3.js

I'm trying to build a "stacked normalized horizontal bar chart" using D3.js v5.

I found an Observable notebook which shows exactly what I need :
https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-normalized-horizontal-bar

I would like to display this exact chart in a "classical" HTML page.

I don't understand how am I supposed to do this : do I need to copy every line of the example (in reverse order) into a Javascript file, and then embed it in the HTML page ?

My final goal is to create a VueJs 2 component to display this kind of charts.

I'm a bit lost, and I'd really appreciate some help to get started...

Comment: I'm confused: what does TypeScript have to do with that notebook?

Comment: I think I have been misled by the "strange" function scopes. It's actually Javascript, I have edited my question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: [This guide](https://observablehq.com/@observablehq/downloading-and-embedding-notebooks) explains how to export the code of notebooks, to be hosted outside of observablehq.

Comment: See this thread for an ongoing discussion. https://talk.observablehq.com/t/i-want-to-learn-d3-i-don-t-want-to-learn-observable-is-that-ok/1957 In my experience migrating an 'Observable' to vanilla JS requires a significant amount of work